# Calculate difference from a reference row in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, row, dataframe

In Pandas I have a data frame of this type:

```
                       value
SampleGroup   sample              
Group1        ref      18.1
              smp1     NaN
              smp2     20.3
              smp3     30.0
              smp4     23.8
              smp5     23.2
```

What I want do do is to add a new column where the reference (ref) has been subtracted from all samples (smp). 
Like this:

```
                       value   deltaValue
SampleGroup   sample              
Group1        ref      18.1    0
              smp1     NaN     NaN
              smp2     20.3    2.2
              smp3     30.0    11.9
              smp4     23.8    5.7
              smp5     23.2    5.1
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post code to reproduce your df thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I knocked up the following which worked for me:

```
In [327]:

t="""sample value
ref      18.1
              smp1     NaN
              smp2     20.3
              smp3     30.0
              smp4     23.8
              smp5     23.2"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df
Out[327]:
  sample  value
0    ref   18.1
1   smp1    NaN
2   smp2   20.3
3   smp3   30.0
4   smp4   23.8
5   smp5   23.2
In [328]:

df['Group'] = 'Group1'
df
Out[328]:
  sample  value   Group
0    ref   18.1  Group1
1   smp1    NaN  Group1
2   smp2   20.3  Group1
3   smp3   30.0  Group1
4   smp4   23.8  Group1
5   smp5   23.2  Group1
In [329]:

df1 = df.set_index(['Group', 'sample'])
df1
Out[329]:
               value
Group  sample       
Group1 ref      18.1
       smp1      NaN
       smp2     20.3
       smp3     30.0
       smp4     23.8
       smp5     23.2

In [337]:

df1['deltaValue'] = df1['value'].sub(df1.loc[('Group1','ref')]['value'])
df1
Out[337]:
               value  deltaValue
Group  sample                   
Group1 ref      18.1         0.0
       smp1      NaN         NaN
       smp2     20.3         2.2
       smp3     30.0        11.9
       smp4     23.8         5.7
       smp5     23.2         5.1
```

Also the following worked:

```
df1['deltaValue'] = df1['value'] - df1.loc[('Group1','ref')]['value']
```

Comment: I had to add a `u` to the beginning of the definition of `t` to avoid an IO error. So `t=u"""sample value...`.

Comment: OK. Just wanted other 2.7 users without much knowledge (like me) to know why they'd get an error with this.

Comment: @EdChum Thank you so much! You made it look so easy ;) Sorry for not posting the code in my question; I appreciate you taking the time anyway.

Comment: It did resolve my question, thanks. It works on my current dataset, but do you have any suggestions on what I would do if i had two groups with separate reference samples? (Group1: ref1, smp1, smp2, etc.; Group2: ref2, smp3, smp4, etc.)

Comment: @AudunB Could you post that as a new question I have an answer: `def func(x):
    return x - df1.loc(axis=0)[x.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[0], 'ref'].values[0]

df1.groupby(level=0)['value'].apply(func)` let me know if this works for you

Comment: @EdChum Thanks! I've posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258974/subtracting-group-specific-value-from-rows-in-pandas