# Subtract a different reference value for each group of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I searched and found this answer which is close but I can't quite see how to apply it to my own situation, as my reference values are not stored within the same dataframe.

[Subtracting group specific value from rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258974/subtracting-group-specific-value-from-rows-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have a data frame as follows, I want to subtract a different reference value from the "Isotropic Shift" column depending on which Nucleus is present (in this case C and H but in principle any value from the periodic table is possible):

```
REF_H = 30
REF_C = 180
df
    Atom Number Nucleus  Isotropic Shift
0             1       C          49.3721
1             2       C          52.9650
2             3       C          36.3443
3             4       C          50.8163
4             5       C          50.0493
5             6       C          49.7985
6             7       H          24.0772
7             8       H          23.7986
8             9       H          24.2922
9            10       H          24.1632
10           11       H          24.1572
11           12       C         102.9401
```

So I would like this to return a delta column where the value is the corresponding Ref_H or Ref_C value minus the isotropic shift:

```
modifieddf.tail(2)
    Atom Number Nucleus  Isotropic Shift    Delta
10           11       H          24.1572   5.8428
11           12       C         102.9401  77.0599
```

So far the best I've come up with is this:

```
def generateHandC(df):
    h = df[df['Nucleus'] == 'H']
    h['delta'] = REF_H - h['Isotropic Shift']
    c = df[df['Nucleus'] == 'C']
    c['delta'] = REF_C - c['Isotropic Shift']
    return h, c

generateHandC(df)

Output:
(    Atom Number Nucleus  Isotropic Shift   delta
6             7       H          24.0772  5.9228
7             8       H          23.7986  6.2014
8             9       H          24.2922  5.7078
9            10       H          24.1632  5.8368
10           11       H          24.1572  5.8428
14           15       H          28.3212  1.6788
15           16       H          28.0110  1.9890
17           18       H          29.2324  0.7676
18           19       H          26.7298  3.2702,     Atom Number Nucleus  Isotropic Shift     delta
0             1       C          49.3721  130.6279
1             2       C          52.9650  127.0350
2             3       C          36.3443  143.6557
3             4       C          50.8163  129.1837
4             5       C          50.0493  129.9507
5             6       C          49.7985  130.2015
11           12       C         102.9401   77.0599
13           14       C         122.3188   57.6812)
```

But this is definitely not optimal, it returns the data frame as a list and throws me a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Ideally I want to return the original dataframe plus an extra column for the delta values. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create a column call reference value and populate with the correct values and then you can delta the columns?  If this is part of a process create the function to add the reference values column then calculate delta and then drop the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `Nucleus` by `dict` and then substract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
REF_H = 30
REF_C = 180
d = {'C': REF_C, 'H':REF_H}
df['Delta'] =  df.Nucleus.map(d).sub(df['Isotropic Shift'])
print (df)
    Atom  Number Nucleus  Isotropic Shift     Delta
0      0       1       C          49.3721  130.6279
1      1       2       C          52.9650  127.0350
2      2       3       C          36.3443  143.6557
3      3       4       C          50.8163  129.1837
4      4       5       C          50.0493  129.9507
5      5       6       C          49.7985  130.2015
6      6       7       H          24.0772    5.9228
7      7       8       H          23.7986    6.2014
8      8       9       H          24.2922    5.7078
9      9      10       H          24.1632    5.8368
10    10      11       H          24.1572    5.8428
11    11      12       C         102.9401   77.0599
```

Comment: I was going to use apply, but this is much nicer

Comment: Thanks you, this worked perfectly and I can see the map function being really useful for me in the future as well!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.ix[df.Nucleus == 'H','Reference Value'] = 30
df.ix[df.Nucleus == 'C','Reference Value'] = 180

df['delta'] = df['Reference Value'] - df['Isotropic Shift']

Atom Number     Nucleus    Isotropic Shift    Reference Value    delta
1               C          49.3721            180.0              130.6279 
2               C          52.9650            180.0              127.0350 
3               C          36.3443            180.0              143.6557 
4               C          50.8163            180.0              129.1837 
5               C          50.0493            180.0              129.9507 
6               C          49.7985            180.0              130.2015 
7               H          24.0772            30.0               5.9228 
8               H          23.7986            30.0               6.2014 
9               H          24.2922            30.0               5.7078 
10              H          24.1632            30.0               5.8368 
11              H          24.1572            30.0               5.8428 
12              C          102.9401           180.0              77.0599
```