# Pandas groupby subtract a reference row from the rest of rows in group same length

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to subtract the reference group cq from all the other things in the biorep,assay group using pandas or i guess general python. Compact or eloquent if possible. This is dead simple in R but can't figure it out here

```
biorep  well          sample    assay   cq
  1      C1            spA      MSGN1   10
  1      C2            spA      MSGN1   15
  1      C3            spA      MSGN1   20
  1      C4            ref      MSGN1   5
  2      C1            spB      MSGN1   12 
  2      C2            spB      MSGN1   15
  2      C3            spB      MSGN1   20
  2      C4            ref      MSGN1   4
```

I would like to group by biorep and assay. And for each of those groups subtract rep from the other things in the group. So i should end up with something like this.
l.

```
biorep  well          sample    assay   cq  delta
  1      C1            spA      MSGN1   10       5
  1      C2            spA      MSGN1   15       10
  1      C3            spA      MSGN1   20       15
  1      C4            ref      MSGN1   5.        0
  2      C1            spB      MSGN1   12        8
  2      C2            spB      MSGN1   15       11
  2      C3            spB      MSGN1   20       16
  2      C4            ref      MSGN1   4         0
```

I know this should be dead easy but I am having trouble even with the suggestions from stackoverflow. I have tried using this suggestion which is the top one i find [Subtracting group specific value from rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258974/subtracting-group-specific-value-from-rows-in-pandas) but to no avail. I get these NaN's. All the other suggestions dont seem relevant or have had trouble googling for this issue. Anyone have an idea here?

```
def func(grp):
    ref =   grp.loc[grp['sample'] == 'No Spacer Control','cq']
    grp['delta'] =   grp[grp['sample'] == 'No Spacer Control']['cq'] - ref
    return grp

summry.groupby(['biorep','assay']).apply(func)
```

```
   biorep     sample       assay        cq         delta
         1    No Spacer Control HPRT    25.237209       0.0
         1      spMSGN1_1       HPRT    25.632444       NaN
         1      spMSGN1_10      HPRT    25.298286       NaN
         1      spMSGN1_11      HPRT    25.130593       NaN
         1      spMSGN1_2       PRT     25.371607       NaN
```

Comment: Please don't post code/data/error messages as images. Post the formatted text directly here on SO.

Comment: Why do not use `plate` column into the group?

Comment: sorry i shouldnt have included it . in this specific experiment its not relevant.

Comment: fixed no longer an image

Comment: i got rid of plate.  My example was a little confusing. I think it is now harmonized

Comment: Out of curiosity - what was the R approach you were trying to replicate?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dataframe from ref values and merge it with your original dataframe:

```
df_ref = df.loc[df['sample'] == 'ref', ['biorep', 'assay', 'cq']]

df = df.merge(df_ref, how='left', on=['biorep', 'assay'], suffixes=('', '_ref'))
df['delta'] = df['cq'] - df['cq_ref']
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work. I was also hoping to see somethign with the groupby logic as there are plenty of other within group operations that i would like to get to and this example is a good proxy for them.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** after your edit:

Try:

```
compute_delta = lambda x: x.loc[x['sample'].ne('ref'), 'cq'] \
                           .sub(x.loc[x['sample'].eq('ref'), 'cq'].squeeze())

df['delta'] = df.groupby(['biorep', 'assay'], as_index=False) \
                .apply(compute_delta).droplevel(0).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print(df)

# Output
   biorep well sample  assay  cq  delta
0       1   C1    spA  MSGN1  10      5
1       1   C2    spA  MSGN1  15     10
2       1   C3    spA  MSGN1  20     15
3       1   C4    ref  MSGN1   5      0
4       2   C1    spB  MSGN1  12      8
5       2   C2    spB  MSGN1  15     11
6       2   C3    spB  MSGN1  20     16
7       2   C4    ref  MSGN1   4      0
```

Comment: @SuperCal123. My version doesn't require any order of `ref` row for a group...

Comment: Thank you i will test this out. and get back to apportion the checkmark etc. I much appreciate all the different methods. Learning a lot hopefully this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given the order of the records, you can subtract the last `cq` from the group, as long as you include `plate` in your grouping.

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby(['biorep','assay', 'plate'])['cq'].apply(lambda x: x.sub(x.iloc[-1]))
```

Output

```
   plate well  biorep sample  assay  cq  delta
0      1   C1       1    spA  MSGN1  10      5
1      1   C2       1    spA  MSGN1  15     10
2      1   C3       1    spA  MSGN1  20     15
3      1   C4       1    ref  MSGN1   5      0
4      2   C1       1    spB  MSGN1  12      8
5      2   C2       1    spB  MSGN1  15     11
6      2   C3       1    spB  MSGN1  20     16
7      2   C4       1    ref  MSGN1   4      0
```

Comment: Is there a logic that doesnt require order? I dont think i will be able to always ensure that order as that might be fragile. The reference name is the thing i can 100% be sure of. I can appreciate i can always sort it however.

Comment: And thank you for the answer. It is helpful.